# Word 2010 VBA to select printer without changing system default printer

Tags: vba, printing, word-2010

In Word 2010, I'm trying to create a macro that sets the current printer to a specific color printer on our network, without making that printer the user's system default printer. I've hacked together some code below from samples I've found on the web. Everything works, except that the SetColorPrinterEast Sub changes the user's system default printer, which I do not want. I suspect the DoNotSetAsSysDefault in that sub is not working as intended, but I don't know what to do about it. See the comments in the code for further explanation. Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

```
'I found the code block below on the web. I don't understand it, but
'it seems to work properly with the "SetDefaultPrinter"
'Sub below to get the system default printer.    
Public Declare Function GetProfileString Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "GetProfileStringA" _
        (ByVal lpAppName As String, _
         ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
         ByVal lpDefault As String, _
         ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
         ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

' This code successfully sets the document to print from
' the system default printer.
Public Sub SetDefaultPrinter()

    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim intReturn As Integer
    strReturn = Space(255)
    intReturn = GetProfileString("Windows", ByVal "device", "", _
    strReturn, Len(strReturn))
    If intReturn Then
        strReturn = UCase(Left(strReturn, InStr(strReturn, ",") - 1))
    End If

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrintSetup)
        .Printer = strReturn
        .DoNotSetAsSysDefault = True
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub

' This code correctly sets the printer to a specific color printer
' on our network. The problem is that it makes that printer
' the user's system default printer. I would think that the
' .DoNotSetAsSysDefault = True line would solve this problem
' but still this sub changes the user's system default printer.

Public Sub SetColorPrinterEast()

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrintSetup)
        .Printer = "\\[*NETWORK PATH*]\Color Printer East"
        .DoNotSetAsSysDefault = True
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem a few years back, got around it by storing the current default print in a variable, changing the default printer to the one I need, printing, then changing the default printer back to users original default.

This was designed and written for Word 2003 but has continued to work in Word 2010.

Here is the specific code I used:

```
'Define Printer to add and printer to delete
Const PrintPath = "\\prn001l0003\Colour04"
Const PrintDeletePath = "\\prn001l0003\Colour02"


' Used to see what printers are set up on the user, and to set a new network printer
Public Declare Function EnumPrinters Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "EnumPrintersA" (ByVal flags As Long, ByVal name As String, _
        ByVal Level As Long, pPrinterEnum As Long, ByVal cdBuf As Long, pcbNeeded As Long, pcReturned As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function PtrToStr Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal RetVal As String, ByVal Ptr As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function StrLen Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal Ptr As Long) As Long
Const PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS = &H4
Const PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL = &H2



Public Sub PrintLetter(ByRef LetterBrochures() As String)
'Print the document

    Dim STDprinter As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Call CheckPrinterLoaded     ' Get users loaded printers, remove any old printers used here,
                                ' and add printer I want to users printers

    STDprinter = Application.ActivePrinter  ' store the current default printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = PrintPath ' change default printer to want I want

    On Error GoTo printLetterError

    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone    ' prevent Word showing any alert/warnings etc

    With ActiveDocument     '  first page is letterhead from tray 2, all others from tray 1, print
        .PageSetup.FirstPageTray = 3 ' 3 = Tray 2 on MFLaser
        .PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = 1  ' 1 = Tray 1 on MFLaser
        .PrintOut Background:=False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll     ' enable Word alets/warning etc
    Application.ActivePrinter = STDprinter 'change back users default printer

    Exit Sub
printLetterError:
    MsgBox "Error printing letter" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    ActiveDocument.Close False
    End
End Sub


Public Function CheckPrinterLoaded()
'get users printers
'look for and delete defined printer, PrintDeletePath
'add printer I want to users printers, PrintPath

    Dim StrPrinters As Variant, x As Long
    Dim StrSetPrinter As String
    Dim objNetwork
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    StrPrinters = ListPrinters

    'Fist check whether the array is filled with anything, by calling another function, IsBounded.
    If IsBounded(StrPrinters) Then
        For x = LBound(StrPrinters) To UBound(StrPrinters)
            If StrPrinters(x) = PrintDeletePath Then
                objNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection PrintDeletePath
            End If
        Next x
        objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrintPath
    Else
        MsgBox "No printers found"
    End If

End Function


Private Function ListPrinters() As Variant
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean
    Dim iBufferRequired As Long
    Dim iBufferSize As Long
    Dim iBuffer() As Long
    Dim iEntries As Long
    Dim iIndex As Long
    Dim strPrinterName As String
    Dim iDummy As Long
    Dim iDriverBuffer() As Long
    Dim StrPrinters() As String

    iBufferSize = 3072

    ReDim iBuffer((iBufferSize \ 4) - 1) As Long

    'EnumPrinters will return a value False if the buffer is not big enough
    bSuccess = EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS Or PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, vbNullString, 1, iBuffer(0), iBufferSize, iBufferRequired, iEntries)

    If Not bSuccess Then
        If iBufferRequired > iBufferSize Then
            iBufferSize = iBufferRequired
            Debug.Print "iBuffer too small. Trying again with "; iBufferSize & " bytes."
            ReDim iBuffer(iBufferSize \ 4) As Long
        End If
        'Try again with new buffer
        bSuccess = EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS Or PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, vbNullString, 1, iBuffer(0), iBufferSize, iBufferRequired, iEntries)
    End If

    If Not bSuccess Then
        'Enumprinters returned False
        MsgBox "Error enumerating printers."
        Exit Function
    Else
        'Enumprinters returned True, use found printers to fill the array
        ReDim StrPrinters(iEntries - 1)
        For iIndex = 0 To iEntries - 1
            'Get the printername
            strPrinterName = Space$(StrLen(iBuffer(iIndex * 4 + 2)))
            iDummy = PtrToStr(strPrinterName, iBuffer(iIndex * 4 + 2))
            StrPrinters(iIndex) = strPrinterName
        Next iIndex
    End If

    ListPrinters = StrPrinters

End Function


Private Function IsBounded(vArray As Variant) As Boolean
    'If the variant passed to this function is an array, the function will return True; otherwise it will return False
    On Error Resume Next
    IsBounded = IsNumeric(UBound(vArray))

End Function
```